# Is it possible to add revocation checking to the dictionary without using a timestamp?

Tags: java, cryptography, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I am working on a solution that allows signing using p12 certificate on a remote server.

First, I have the digest of the document which is calculated on a server and then I send it for signature on another server.

Right after I added the revocation check as well as a timestamp during the signature, using the following code:

```
public class ServerA {
    public static ExternalCMSPAdESService service;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("Doc 2.pdf"));
        DSSDocument documentToSign = new FileDocument(new File("Doc 2.pdf"));
        PAdESSignatureParameters signatureParameters = new PAdESSignatureParameters();
        SignatureFieldParameters parameters = new SignatureFieldParameters();

        DigestAlgorithm digestAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithm.SHA256;
        signatureParameters.setDigestAlgorithm(digestAlgorithm);
        signatureParameters.setSignatureLevel(SignatureLevel.PAdES_BASELINE_B);
        //signatureParameters.setGenerateTBSWithoutCertificate(true);

        IPdfObjFactory pdfObjFactory = new ServiceLoaderPdfObjFactory();
        AbstractPDFSignatureService pdfSignatureService = (AbstractPDFSignatureService) pdfObjFactory.newPAdESSignatureService();

        byte[] documentDigest = pdfSignatureService.digest(documentToSign, signatureParameters);

        byte[] signedDigest = Engine.getSignedCMSignedData(documentDigest);
        DSSDocument finalDoc = pdfSignatureService.sign(documentToSign, signedDigest, signatureParameters);

        CommonCertificateVerifier commonCertificateVerifier = new CommonCertificateVerifier();
        commonCertificateVerifier.setCrlSource(new OnlineCRLSource());
        commonCertificateVerifier.setOcspSource(new OnlineOCSPSource());
        commonCertificateVerifier.setCheckRevocationForUntrustedChains(true);
        service = new ExternalCMSPAdESService(commonCertificateVerifier);
        TimestampDataLoader timestampDataLoader = new TimestampDataLoader();// uses the specific content-type
        OnlineTSPSource tsa1 = new OnlineTSPSource("http://dss.nowina.lu/pki-factory/tsa/ee-good-tsa");
        tsa1.setDataLoader(timestampDataLoader);
        service.setTspSource(tsa1);
        PAdESSignatureParameters extensionParameters = new PAdESSignatureParameters();
        extensionParameters.setSignatureLevel(SignatureLevel.PAdES_BASELINE_LT);
        commonCertificateVerifier.setCheckRevocationForUntrustedChains(true);

        DSSDocument extendedDocument = service.extendDocument(finalDoc, extensionParameters);

        save(finalDoc);
        save2(extendedDocument);

    }

    private static void save2(DSSDocument signedDocument) {
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("DSS-2.pdf")) {
            Utils.copy(signedDocument.openStream(), fos);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, "Unable to save file : " + e.getMessage(), ButtonType.CLOSE);
            alert.showAndWait();
            return;
        }
    }
    private static void save(DSSDocument signedDocument) {
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("DSS.pdf")) {
            Utils.copy(signedDocument.openStream(), fos);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, "Unable to save file : " + e.getMessage(), ButtonType.CLOSE);
            alert.showAndWait();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

and for server B, I added the timestamp part to the signature:

```
public class ServerB {
    static PadesCMSSignedDataBuilder padesCMSSignedDataBuilder;
    public static String pathCert = "Barid-Media-Client_Authentification.p12";


    public static byte[] getSignedCMSignedData(byte[] documentDigest) throws Exception {
        CommonCertificateVerifier commonCertificateVerifier = new CommonCertificateVerifier();

        commonCertificateVerifier.setCrlSource(new OnlineCRLSource());
        commonCertificateVerifier.setOcspSource(new OnlineOCSPSource());
        commonCertificateVerifier.setCheckRevocationForUntrustedChains(true);

        padesCMSSignedDataBuilder = new PadesCMSSignedDataBuilder(commonCertificateVerifier);
        SignatureTokenConnection signingToken = new Pkcs12SignatureToken(
                "certificate.p12",
                new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("123456".toCharArray()));
        DSSPrivateKeyEntry privateKey = getKey(
                "certificate.p12",
                "123456");

        PAdESSignatureParameters parameters = new PAdESSignatureParameters();
        parameters.setDigestAlgorithm(DigestAlgorithm.SHA256);
        parameters.setEncryptionAlgorithm(EncryptionAlgorithm.RSA);
        parameters.setSignatureLevel(SignatureLevel.PAdES_BASELINE_B);
        parameters.setSigningCertificate(privateKey.getCertificate());

        ToBeSigned dataToSign = getDataToSign(documentDigest, parameters);
        SignatureValue signatureValue = signingToken.sign(dataToSign, DigestAlgorithm.SHA256, privateKey);
        return generateCMSSignedData(documentDigest, parameters, signatureValue);
    }

    protected static byte[] generateCMSSignedData(byte[] messageDigest, final PAdESSignatureParameters parameters,
                                                  final SignatureValue signatureValue) throws Exception {
        final SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = parameters.getSignatureAlgorithm();
        final SignatureLevel signatureLevel = parameters.getSignatureLevel();
        Objects.requireNonNull(signatureAlgorithm, "SignatureAlgorithm cannot be null!");
        Objects.requireNonNull(signatureLevel, "SignatureLevel must be defined!");

        SigningResponseWithEvidence signingResponseWithEvidence = new SigningResponseWithEvidence();

        final CustomContentSigner customContentSigner = new CustomContentSigner(signatureAlgorithm.getJCEId(), signatureValue.getValue());

        final SignerInfoGeneratorBuilder signerInfoGeneratorBuilder = padesCMSSignedDataBuilder.getSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(parameters, messageDigest);

        final CMSProcessableByteArray content = new CMSProcessableByteArray(messageDigest);

        final CMSSignedDataGenerator generator = padesCMSSignedDataBuilder.createCMSSignedDataGenerator(parameters, customContentSigner,
                signerInfoGeneratorBuilder, null);

        CMSSignedData data = CMSUtils.generateDetachedCMSSignedData(generator, content);

        data = signTimeStamps(data,false).getCmsSignedData();

        return data.getEncoded();
    }


    private static ResultTimeStamp signTimeStamps(CMSSignedData cmsSignedData,
                                                  boolean cancelOnErrorTsa) throws Exception {
        SignerInformationStore signerStore = cmsSignedData.getSignerInfos();
        java.util.Iterator iterator = ((java.util.Collection)signerStore.getSigners()).iterator();
        java.util.List newSigners = new java.util.ArrayList();
        CMSSignedData returned = null;
        ResultTimeStamp resultTimeStamp = new ResultTimeStamp();
        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Object result = signTimeStamp((SignerInformation)iterator.next(),cancelOnErrorTsa);

            if(result != null)
                newSigners.add(result);
        }
        if(newSigners.size() != 0) {
            returned = CMSSignedData.replaceSigners(cmsSignedData, new SignerInformationStore(newSigners));
            resultTimeStamp.setSuccessTsa(true);
        } else {
            returned = cmsSignedData;
            resultTimeStamp.setSuccessTsa(false);
        }
        resultTimeStamp.setCmsSignedData(returned);
        return resultTimeStamp;
    }

    public static Object signTimeStamp(SignerInformation next, boolean cancelOnErrorTsa
    ) throws Exception {
        AttributeTable unsignedAttributes = next.getUnsignedAttributes();
        ASN1EncodableVector vector = new ASN1EncodableVector();
        SignerInformation newSigner = null;
        if (unsignedAttributes != null)
        {
            vector = unsignedAttributes.toASN1EncodableVector();
        }
        int codestatus = 0;
        try {
            codestatus = initializeSSLConnexion();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if(!cancelOnErrorTsa) {
                throw new ProSignServerGlobalException("014");
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        if(codestatus == 503) {
            if(!cancelOnErrorTsa) {
                throw new ProSignServerGlobalException("014");
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            try {
                TSA tsaClient = new TSA("https://tsa.baridesign.ma:8443/servlets/Horodatage/MetaTIME/TimeStampService/TSPService",
                        pathCert,
                        "123456");
                java.security.MessageDigest mda = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

                byte[] digest = mda.digest(next.getSignature());

                byte[] token = tsaClient.getTimeStampToken(digest);

                ASN1ObjectIdentifier oid = PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_aa_signatureTimeStampToken;
                ASN1Encodable signatureTimeStamp = new org.bouncycastle.asn1.cms.Attribute(oid, new DERSet(ASN1Primitive.fromByteArray(token)));


                vector.add(signatureTimeStamp);
                newSigner = SignerInformation.replaceUnsignedAttributes(next, new AttributeTable(vector));
                if (newSigner == null) return next;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if(!cancelOnErrorTsa) {
                    throw new ProSignServerGlobalException("014");
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }


        return newSigner;
    }
    public static int initializeSSLConnexion() throws Exception {
        int codestatus = 200;

        try{
            KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            clientStore.load(new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils
                    .getFile(pathCert)), "123456".toCharArray());

            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            keyManagerFactory.init(clientStore, "123456".toCharArray());
            KeyManager[] keyManager = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();

            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            trustStore.load(new FileInputStream("C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_221/lib/security/cacerts"),
                    "changeit".toCharArray());

            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
            TrustManager[] trustManager = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(keyManager, trustManager, new SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
            URL url = new URL("https://tsa.baridesign.ma:8443/servlets/Horodatage/MetaTIME/TimeStampService/TSPService");

            HttpsURLConnection urlConn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if(urlConn.getResponseCode() == 503) {
                codestatus = 503;
            }
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            System.out.println("1");
            codestatus = 503;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            codestatus = 503;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            System.out.println("3");
            codestatus = 503;
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            System.out.println("4");
            codestatus = 503;
        } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            System.out.println("5");
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            System.out.println("6");
            codestatus = 503;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            codestatus = 503;
            throw new Exception("Failed to get TSA response from '" );
        }
        return codestatus;
    }

    public static DSSPrivateKeyEntry getKey(String certificate, String pin) throws Exception {
        try (Pkcs12SignatureToken signatureToken = new Pkcs12SignatureToken(certificate,
                new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(pin.toCharArray()))) {
            List<DSSPrivateKeyEntry> keys = signatureToken.getKeys();
            KSPrivateKeyEntry dssPrivateKeyEntry = (KSPrivateKeyEntry) keys.get(0);
            DSSPrivateKeyEntry entry = signatureToken.getKey(dssPrivateKeyEntry.getAlias(),
                    new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(pin.toCharArray()));
            return entry;
        }
    }

    public static ToBeSigned getDataToSign(byte[] messageDigest, final PAdESSignatureParameters parameters) throws DSSException {
        final SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = parameters.getSignatureAlgorithm();
        final CustomContentSigner customContentSigner = new CustomContentSigner(signatureAlgorithm.getJCEId());

        SignerInfoGeneratorBuilder signerInfoGeneratorBuilder = padesCMSSignedDataBuilder.getSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(parameters, messageDigest);

        final CMSSignedDataGenerator gn = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        final CMSProcessableByteArray content = new CMSProcessableByteArray(messageDigest);

        CMSSignedData originalData = CMSUtils.generateDetachedCMSSignedData(gn, content);

        final CMSSignedDataGenerator generator = padesCMSSignedDataBuilder.createCMSSignedDataGenerator(parameters, customContentSigner,
                signerInfoGeneratorBuilder, originalData);


        CMSUtils.generateDetachedCMSSignedData(generator, content);

        final byte[] dataToSign = customContentSigner.getOutputStream().toByteArray();
        return new ToBeSigned(dataToSign);
    }
}
```

**But in this case what I'm looking for is not to have to use a timestamp**

**Now what I'm looking for is to find a solution to add revocation checking in the intended area (still signing with esig/Dss) without adding a timestamp.**

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I just modified the sample source code that works using a timestamp. But I am now trying to have the same revocation check without having to use a timestamp

Comment: @Mkl, have any idea about this question ?